# Does the iOS app stop supporting horizontal scrolling?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

About two years ago, I posted [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20487/191404) on Meta to raise the horizontal scrolling issue then existing in the iOS app. Owing a big thank to the Community, after one or two version updates this issue was fixed by introducing the horizontal scrolling feature. But now, it seems to me that the horizontal scrolling feature has disappeared: again, there is no way to read complete lines of math contents that are too long for the phone screen to hold.

I just want to know what would be the reason to retract the horizontal scrolling in the iOS app (which accounted a great deal for the amazing user experience of this app, making browsing even more attractive than on PC, at least in my perspective). And if possible, will the Community kindly recover it in the coming versions?

Thanks!

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.2, shipping soon.

Something happened when migrating to the new MathJax version/CDN and the element I was scrolling on got a different CSS class.